# jQuery don't work on phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova

This code works perfectly in different browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari), but in PhoneGap, when I click the button 'login' the logme function does not work.

I have tried to replace click by vclick,
or //ajax.gooogleapis.com/.... by file://ajax.goo.... but it does not work.

Do you have an idea of the problem?

thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* { font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; line-height: 30px }
.title { background:#333; color: white; }
.success { color: #060; font-weight: bold; }
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var apiURL = "localhost/wordpress/api/";
var noncestring = "get_nonce/?";
var authstring = "user/generate_auth_cookie/?";
var poststring = "posts_auth/create_post/?";
var username, password;
var nonce, cookie;

$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#logme').click(function() {

        jQuery(function($) {
            username = document.forms["logme"].elements["username"].value;
            password = document.forms["logme"].elements["password"].value;
        });

        getNonce("user", "generate_auth_cookie");

        function getNonce(controller, method) { 
            $.getJSON(apiURL + noncestring + "controller=" + controller + "&method=" + method, function(data) {

                var items = [];
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    if (key == "nonce") {
                        nonce = val;
                        $('.status').append("<br>Nonce acquired for controller '" + controller + "', method '" + method + "': " + val);

                        // Add additional methods here. Could make this a switch statement. 
                        if (method == "generate_auth_cookie") 
                            createAuthCookie();

                        if (method == "create_post")
                            createPost();

                        getid();

                    }
                });
            });
        }


        function createAuthCookie() {

            $('.status').append("<br>creating -> auth cookie with nonce " + nonce);

            var authCookieURL = apiURL + authstring + "nonce=" + nonce + "&username=" + username + "&password=" + password;

            $.getJSON(authCookieURL, function(data) {
                var items = [];
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {

                    if (key == "cookie") {
                        cookie = val;
                        $('.status').append("<br>Auth cookie -> acquired! value: " + val);

                        // Get a new nonce to create the post:
                        getNonce("posts_auth", "create_post");

                    }
                }); 
            });
        }

        function getid() {

            $('.status').append("<br>Get -> id");

            var authCookieURL = apiURL + authstring + "nonce=" + nonce + "&username=" + username + "&password=" + password;

            $.getJSON(authCookieURL, function(data) {
                var items = [];
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {

                    if (key == "user") {
                        user = val;
                        $('.status').append("<br>id -> acquired! value: " + user.id + "<br>username -> acquired! value: " + user.username + "<br>nicename -> acquired! value: " + user.nicename + "<br>email -> acquired! value: " + user.email + "<br>avatar url -> acquired! value: " + user.avatar);

                        // Get a new nonce to create the post:
                        getNonce("posts_auth", "create_post");  
                    }
                }); 
            });
        }

        function createPost() {
            $('.status').append("<br>creating -> post with nonce: " + nonce);

            var cookiepart = "&cookie=" + cookie;
            var postContent = "&status=publish&title=NonceTest&content=test+test&author=Alex&categories=Demos&tags=test,api,json";

            $.getJSON(apiURL + poststring + "nonce=" + nonce + cookiepart + postContent, function(data) {
                var items = [];
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    if (key == "status") {
                        console.log("status value: " + val);
                        if (val == "ok") {
                            $('.status').append("<br><span class='success'> -> A new post was successfully created.</span>");
                        }
                    }
                });


            });
        }
    }); 
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="title">Json Test 3</div>
    <form id="loginForm" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8" name="logme"> 
        <fieldset>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
            <label for="email"> Username </label> 
            <input type="text" name="username" id="email" value=""> 
        </div> 
        <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
            <label for="password"> Password </label> 
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value=""> 
        </div>
        <input type="button" data-theme="g" name="submit" id="logme" value=" Login "> 
        </fieldset> 
    </form>
<div class="status">Getting nonce for auth cookie...</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$('document')` should be `$(document)`

Comment: I just tried but it does not change! :(

Comment: jQuery works fine with phonegap, your code is wrong. There are to many errors. Stack overflow isn't a "please fix my code" site

Comment: I'm actually here to fix my code. I'm not here to watch the clouds go !!!
What is the interest of the forum then? I do not ask me to do a code from A to Z, I am currently debbug, and that's why I request the opinion of the community to help me fix my code!

Answer (score 0):

Load jquery as 'http://'. I had this problem too when trying to load remote files with Phonegap (or Ionicframework), just '//' does not seem to work.

Comment: Are you sure you have internet access through the Phonegap app then?

Comment: Yes, I test with the applications 'PhoneGap' & 'Cordova Browser' on my iphone (and sources are loaded directly from the web).

Comment: Do you have access to localhost from your iphone?

Comment: Sorry I do not have detailed you, but in my front-end code, the apiURL isn't `"localhost/wordpress/api/"`, but a remote server `"http://..."`. I did not display the address here because the problem is not with the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery works 100%. The problem is your `apiURL` is not from external server, its just from `localhost`. try test on external server. don't use `localhost`.

Comment: Sorry I do not have detailed you, but in my front-end code, the apiURL isn't `"localhost/wordpress/api/"`, but a remote server `"http://..."`. I did not display the address here because the problem is not with the back-end.